# Gradient in Cylindrical ccordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How can I express grad of $\Phi$ in cylindrical coordinates?. In fact I wanted to check the vector $\nabla\Phi$ is perpendicular to a surface $\Phi=c$ where $c$ is a constant. Where to start? Thank you.

Comment: $\nabla \Phi (r,\theta,z) =\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial r}\hat{\bf{r}} +\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta}\hat{\bf{\theta}}+ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\hat{\bf{z}}$

Answer (score 2):

As given in the comments: 
$$\nabla \Phi (r,\theta,z) =\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial r}\hat{\bf{r}} +\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta}\hat{\bf{\theta}}+ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\hat{\bf{z}}$$